# How to get user email address from twitter, using oAuth?

Tags: twitter, oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-usi)

Using oAuth I'm able to sucessfully login and forward it back to my PHP application.

How can I get the email address of the authenticated person? At this point I just have an authenticated oAuth.

Can you direct me to a tutorial?

Comment: check this link : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not doable.

[Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599621/72478)

> The user's email address can not be retrieved via the API.  This is a deliberate design decision by the API team.
>
> **UPDATE 2015.08.18:**
>
> It is possible to request an email address from users, but it requires your app to be whitelisted...

Comment: Exactly, it's not listed in the available user fields on [Twitter's API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554755/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users%C2%A0show)

Comment: This has changed.   It is now possible to get the user's email address (if they permit it) by using Twitter xAuth.  More info here:  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials