# How can I get twitter user profile in android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

How can I get the user name, email, location, avatar, etc., of an authenticated user of Twitter in Android via the API?

I wrote the code below, but it always returns `null` at `twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());`

```
public User getUserInfo(Object accessToken) 
{
    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(mConsumer.getConsumerKey());
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(mConsumer.getConsumerSecret());
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance();
    try 
    {
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken((AccessToken) accessToken);
        return twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

---

I found another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119345/how-to-get-user-email-address-from-twitter-using-oauth). People said that unable to retrieve email address of authenticated user of Twitter via api. So, How about other information such as fullname, avatar, phone number (if have),...?

Comment: Have you checked this post which I believe it is a possible duplicate of yours [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app)

Comment: ## You can check below link it's working fine for me ## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836358/how-to-get-user-information-form-twitter-api/44491730#44491730