# How to get user data through twitter's Fabric API (Android)

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I've successfully integrated twitter's fabric api in my project 
A twitter login button

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

A manifest permission

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="myfabrickey" />
```

Initialization

```
 //field declerations
         private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "yourtwkey";
            private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "yoursecret";

    //Inside oncreate
          TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
                Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Twitter(authConfig));
  loginButtonTwitter = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        loginButtonTwitter.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });

//Inside onActivityResult
 loginButtonTwitter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

My only question is, how do i get the user data in a json format once i authenticate my account.

Answer (score 12):

Ok! It was quite simple. (was trying to do it during midnight so i guess half of my brain was asleep :P)
Referenced from this link https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-get-user-profile-image/30579/6
In the user object, you'll get all the stuff.

```
  TwitterSession session =
                Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {



                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

                        User user = userResult.data;
                        twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    }

                });
```

Comment: I was having a headache even in a day finding a solution (Had tea as well). thank you so much. At last i got name of the user.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Have you integrated Twitter's Fabric API ?

Comment: compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.7.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

The above is something that Fabric integrates in your build.gradle file. You'll need it.

Comment: @Abhilash do we have to use Fabric for just user info? Isn't twitter's own api providing this?

Answer (score 3):

For those who getting error "verifyCredentials() in AccountService cannot be applied to .. "  Please change the code like below

```
    Call<User> userResult = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true,false);
            userResult.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

                @Override 
                public void failure(TwitterException e) { 

                } 

                @Override 
                public void success(Result<User> userResult) { 

                    User user = userResult.data; 
                    String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl; 

                    try { 
                        Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl); 
                        Log.d("name", user.name); 
                        Log.d("email",user.email); 
                        Log.d("des", user.description); 
                        Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount)); 
                        Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt); 
                    } catch (Exception e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 


                } 

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is how to get user info after login through Twitter using Fabric.

### Here is MainActivity.java class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "your twitter api key";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "your twitter secret key";

    private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
    TextView textView;
    TwitterSession session;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_username);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);

        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

                session = result.data;

                String username = session.getUserName();
                Long userid = session.getUserId();


                textView.setText("Hi " + username);
                getUserData();


            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }

    void getUserData() {
        Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

                        User user = userResult.data;
                        String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

                        try {
                            Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl);
                            Log.d("name", user.name);
                            Log.d("email",user.email);
                            Log.d("des", user.description);
                            Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount));
                            Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                });


    }
}
```

### Here is MainActivity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sourcen.twitterlogin.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="twitter username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


    <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
        android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: twitter doesn't provide email you have to ask for it. Note that

Comment: I'M GETTING: verifyCredentials() in AccountService cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:
 
includeEntities:
Boolean
true  
skipStatus:
Boolean
false  


... } }  (anonymous...sdk.android.core.models.User>)

Comment: You can check below link it's working fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836358/how-to-get-user-information-form-twitter-api/44491730#44491730