# How to get Birthdate from the twitter integration , I am using twitter core SDK

Tags: android

I integrate twitter login, I want to get birthdate from the user. can I get birthdate?? , If yes then please suggest the code. Currently, I integrate twitter through twitter developer website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user data through twitter's Fabric API (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564935/how-to-get-user-data-through-twitters-fabric-api-android)

Comment: Check this video may help you with Twitter integration in Android app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZbtA8tQ1kM

Comment: I am using Twitter core SDK to log in I am not using Fabric API