# django-social-auth : did not save twitter's email

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-socialauth

when I access `127.0.0:8000/associate/twitter`, my django get all the twitter's information except for the email address.

there is no problem in accessing `127.0.0:8000/associate/facebook`, i was just wondering why my django did not get the email of the twitter account?

do anyone have an idea on how to solve my case? 
thanks in advance ...

this is in my settings.py

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID              = '.....'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET          = '.........'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
#twitter
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = '.........'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = '.........'
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377633/oauth-twitter-and-email. Short answer: twitter doesn't provide user email.

Comment: thanks for the reply stalk... now i know the reason :)

Comment: Check this answer of mine for python-social-auth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377633/oauth-twitter-and-email#answer-35039478

Answer (score 5):

twitter does not provide the email. As much you will have access to the data provided when verifying the [credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials)