# Get user's email from Twitter API for External Login Authentication ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have checked a couple of related questions to find an answer to my question, but all to no avail. This question [Can we get email ID from Twitter oauth API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627083/can-we-get-email-id-from-twitter-oauth-api) got me as far as getting the Twitter support to allow the permission on my app below:
[image: Additional permissions]
Using this [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) as a guide and the marked answer's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049927/using-twitter-oauth-via-api-1-1-without-3rd-party-library) (modifying it a little bit)

```
var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
var postBody = "include_email=true";//
resource_url += "?" + postBody;
```

to generate a signature and make a request to get the user's details from twitter results in **401 Unauthorized** in my MVC app.

However, when I use the twitter signature generator tool to generate the authorization header and use fiddler to make a GET request to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true, I get the email only once and I have to regenerate my app keys in twitter to get it again.

Is there a doc on how to generate a valid signature and make a valid request to retrieve the Twitter user email via .Net TwitterAuthentication?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After almost going bald from pulling all my hairs out of my head, I finally got it to work. I found out that the Signature base string was slightly different from the one generated with my code. After little tweaks, I was able to generate a valid signature base string.

In **Startup.cs**, I added access_token and access_secret as claims. I did not use the one found on my app because the users need to invoke a new one as they attempt to login or register:

```
var twitterOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
{
   ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumer_key"],
   ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumer_secret"],
   Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.TwitterAuthenticationProvider
   {
      OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
      {
         context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:twitter:access_token", context.AccessToken));
         context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:twitter:access_secret", context.AccessTokenSecret));
         return Task.FromResult(0);
      }
   },
   BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
   {
      "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
      "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
      "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
      "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
      "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
      "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
      "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
      "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3" // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
    }),
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/twitter/account/ExternalLoginCallback")
};

 app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterOptions);
```

And finally in my controller, I just called my helper class to get the name and email from twitter:

```
    if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider.ToLower() == "twitter")
    {
        string access_token = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "urn:twitter:access_token").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        string access_secret = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "urn:twitter:access_secret").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        TwitterDto response = MyHelper.TwitterLogin(access_token, access_secret, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumer_key"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumer_secret"]);
       // by now response.email should possess the email value you need
    }
```

**Helper class method:**

This was the section I tweaked in order to make a valid request:

> baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url)
>   + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(request_query), "%26", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

```
public static TwitterDto TwitterLogin(string oauth_token, string oauth_token_secret, string oauth_consumer_key, string oauth_consumer_secret)
        {
            // oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            // unique request details
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
                - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

            var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
            var request_query = "include_email=true";
            // create oauth signature
            var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version
                                        );

            baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(request_query), "%26", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
            {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
            }

            // create the request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                            );


            // make the request

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            resource_url += "?include_email=true";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            request.Method = "GET";

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitterDto>(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
    }

    public class TwitterDto
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

This is all you need to get the twitter user's email. I hope it helps someone struggling with this. Please note that the steps mentioned in the question is also very important.

**Updates version .netcore 3.1**

It is very simple to implement the twitter API in .netcore compared to the solution above. First, you need to create an app on Twitter [Create Twitter App](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps/create)

Supply all necessary information such as app name, description, websiteURL (https://example.com will do for local development), and so on. For your callback url, provide the local url you are using. In my case, https://localhost:44318/signin-twitter and ensure that you tick "request email address from users" save and then regenerate the consumer API Keys under the "Keys and tokens" tab see image below: [image]

After you are done with the Twitter administration,
Install the nuget package in your solution in Visual Studio:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter`

Update your .NetCore Application Startup Class (ConfigureServices method) in visual studio to initialize the Twitter Authentication mechanism with the code below:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddTwitter(options => 
        {
            options.ConsumerKey = twitterConsumerApiKey;
            options.ConsumerSecret = twitterConsumerSecretKey;
            options.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
        }); // twitterConsumerApiKey and twitterConsumerSecretkey can be found under the "Keys and tokens" tab of the Twitter App previously created.
```

The process is complete and you should be able to get emails of users upon authentication. For more information check out [Twitter external sign-in setup with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Hi Oluwafemi, is this code still working for you? I'm facing this problem where I'm getting a 401 everytime I try to request https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json for the email.. I've got the permission from Twitter, and when I use the Signature generator from Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/[APPID]) everything works fine. The Authorization Header created by your code looks very much like it, but does not work for me. Do you maybe have a working example?

Comment: @Guido The helper method above used as is should work. It's currently working on all my live sites.

Comment: You were right Oluwafemi, I accidentally send my accesstoken twice instead of the accesstokensecret. So thank you for this, really helped me!

Comment: thanks a lot for code snippet , but I only want to verify user credentials and want to authorize user , how can I do that?

Comment: @Neo the response coming from the twitter Api should contain the user's email. You can use the email to authorize a user.

Comment: Brilliant effort!

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985075/3826175 why this trick with `%26` works but may not work when you need more params like all 3 include_email, include_entities and skip_status.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code to call the GET account/verify_credentials method after the user is logged in with twitter. And it is important to set the parameter include_email to true. When this is set to true email will be returned in the user objects as a string.
I'm using this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter
so that I do not have to write code for handling twitter api requests

```
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(authTwitter);
var verifyResponse = await
    (from acct in twitterCtx.Account
    where (acct.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials) && (acct.IncludeEmail == true)
    select acct)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

see how I have done this here
http://www.bigbrainintelligence.com/Post/get-users-email-address-from-twitter-oauth-ap

it is an easy and clean solution

Comment: the link is broken. try to get here https://web.archive.org/web/20170630200559/http://www.bigbrainintelligence.com/Post/get-users-email-address-from-twitter-oauth-ap

Answer (score 0):

`{METHOD}&{URL_WITHOUT_QUERY_PARAMS}&{OTHER_PARAMS}`

When creating signature GET query parameters must not be a part of `{URL_WITHOUT_QUERY_PARAMS}` but as a part of `{OTHER_PARAMS}`. Note that `{OTHER_PARAMS}` must be sorted alphabetically.

https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

Appendix A.5.1.  Generating Signature Base String

> To generate the signature, it first needs to generate the Signature
> Base String. The request contains the following parameters
> (oauth_signature excluded) which are ordered and concatenated into a
> normalized string:
>
> oauth_consumer_key: dpf43f3p2l4k3l03
> oauth_token: nnch734d00sl2jdk
> oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
> oauth_timestamp: 1191242096
> oauth_nonce: kllo9940pd9333jh
> oauth_version: 1.0
> file: vacation.jpg
> size: original
>
> The following inputs are used to generate the Signature Base String:
>
> 1. GET
> 2. `http://photos.example.net/photos`
> 3. `file=vacation.jpg&oauth_consumer_key=dpf43f3p2l4k3l03&oauth_nonce=kllo9940pd9333jh&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1191242096&oauth_token=nnch734d00sl2jdk&oauth_version=1.0&size=original`
>
> The Signature Base String is:
>
> `GET&http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.example.net%2Fphotos&file%3Dvacation.jpg%26oauth_consumer_key%3Ddpf43f3p2l4k3l03%26oauth_nonce%3Dkllo9940pd9333jh%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1191242096%26oauth_token%3Dnnch734d00sl2jdk%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26size%3Doriginal`