# Get email from twitter OAuth2

Tags: laravel, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite in Laravel to login with Twitter.

I know that not all twitter users have an email attached to their account, but for my application the user does need an email address. I am fine to block logins from people who do not have an email attached, but at the moment every user does have the email field set to null.

I am using this function to redirect to twitter:

```
return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
```

I have already tried using scopes like this:

```
return Socialite::driver($provider)->scopes(['email'])->redirect();
```

But twitter is the only provider that does not allow scopes.

The callback returns the email address for other providers like facebook and google, but there seems to be something that I am missing while using twitter.

For OAuth1 there was a setting somewhere to enable the option to return the email field aswell, but since twitter accepts OAuth2 I can not find this setting anymore in the Twitter developers panel.

Any help would my appreciated since most of the information about this topic is outdated.

Comment: Please check this comment https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/419#issuecomment-264560103 , I have get email after User authentication settings changes on twitter development portal.

Answer (score 5):

Twitter's new Oauth 2.0 user authentication does not *currently* (at the time of writing this answer) provide access to the user's email address, and will require an additional scope to be added. This is on the Twitter API roadmap and is a known feature request.

You can still use OAuth 1.0A and set the option to request the user's email address.

Comment: wow, they recommend moving to OAuth2 but they don't provide scope to get an email. I'm planning to use twitter for social login but twitter is the only popular provider that makes this hard :)

Comment: @aderesh I cannot believe how difficult twitter has made this. I implemented custom oauth solutions for google, facebook, and github all in under 20 min. With twitter it has taken me more than a day and I still don't know how to get the email address which is really the main thing you need if you are going to use a 3rd party for user authentication. Their docs are some of the worst i've seen and I find myself having to leave their site to find information on their own api. I think I am going to ditch twitter authentication.

Comment: Wow, more than a year and a half later and I'm sorry to say that Twitter's OAuth2 still does not have access to user's email.

Comment: Twitter does not exist anymore.

Comment: Shame on Twitter/X - nowadays still not possible to use OAuth 2.0 sign in such many many years can be used for Google/Facebook.

Comment: There's no way that they are going to do anything to implement it at this point - look elsewhere.

Comment: Such as @SteveK wrote, implementing Facebook/Google takes several tens of minutes because of simple OAuth2. Im using AOuth2 for 3rd party sign-in for more than 10 years and nowadays in 2024 because of oldschoold Twitter I had to learn old OAuth1. Lol! For anyone who looks for pure flow/implementation without libraries with million lines of code I recommend to learn OAuth1 flow here https://phppot.com/php/login-with-twitter-using-oauth1-0a-protocol-via-api-in-php/ With this tutorial you will be done in a few hours. Be careful when crating signature https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985075/3826175

Comment: @SteveK to get email see `include_email` at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials I have just successfully implemented OAuth1 including `include_email=true&include_entities=false&skip_status=true` - creating signatures manually is a hell. Official doc helped https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ => Appendix A.5.1.  Generating Signature Base String

Answer (score 3):

The solution was found in the twitter developers dashboard.

First of all go to the settings of your app.

Then you have to fill in a link to your privacy policy & terms page.

After that also enable OAuth 1.0 en then an option pops up to also receive the email address from the user that is trying to log in.