# How to get user information from twitter in android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am integrating twitter in my android app. I am able to authorize the app for the user. Now, I am looking for the API which gives me logged users information like first name, last name, email, etc. 
I had done this for facebook with

facebook.request("me");

Now how to get user info from twitter? 
I am using twitter4j-core-android2.2.3.jar. Plz let me know is there a way to get user info.

Comment: how u done with facebook please explain that

Comment: ## You can check below link it's working fine ##
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836358/how-to-get-user-information-form-twitter-api/44491730#44491730

Answer (score 18):

Finally I got user information.

use the access token you get after

```
accessToken = twitterConnection.getOAuthAccessToken
    (requestToken,editPinCode.getText().toString());

oHelper.storeAccessToken(accessToken);

Log.i("Access Token:", accessToken.getToken());

Log.i("Access Secret:", accessToken.getTokenSecret());

long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

User user = twitterConnection.showUser(userID);

user.getName();
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't know what is "editPinCode", don't know what's "oHelper", but why are so many up vote?

Comment: How to get email id ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tutorials here that can help you get an app running with twitter..

if you just need to retrieve info for a specific user, you can look here  (includes source code):

[Basic Adroid Twitter Integration](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-twitter-reader.html)

If you want to interact with twitter (e.g. post updates etc) then you will need to setup OAuth connection:

[Android and Twitter integratin using OAuth](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true, false).enqueue(new Callback<User>()
        {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> userResult)
            {
                try
                {
                    User user = userResult.data;
//                         twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e)
            {

            }

        });
```

Comment: It works perfect , even some tutorial websites dont match your answer, thanks

Comment: I am not getting email from this.All things I am getting except email.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get **Email** from the **twitter OAuth**  unless or untill your app is whitelisted.
For more Info
[Email ID from Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-his-her-twitter-identit)

Answer (score 0):

You can check bellow code: To get user info you can use Twitter Fabric SDK. Its documentation is [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) and [here](https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio)

```
 twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                AccountService ac = Twitter.getApiClient(result.data).getAccountService();
                ac.verifyCredentials(true, true, new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {
                        String imageUrl = result.data.profileImageUrl;
                        String email = result.data.email;
                        String userName = result.data.name;
                        System.out.println(imageUrl);
                        System.out.println(email);
                        System.out.println(userName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        Log.d("ls",e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Here `twitterButton` is 
`import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;`
In this response you can get All credential without user Email.

Comment: I am getting error verifyCredential() to AccountService can not applied.

Comment: I am not getting email id and mobile number.

Comment: i think fabric no more support twitter login due to which this account service code gives error. i also geting error and now confused how to do this .