# How to get profile information from twitter in android application?

Tags: twitter, android-twitter

That means i want to get the details or profile info of user from twitter in my android application.

Comment: Read [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use OAuth in which your user will authorize your APP to access his/her data and once user has authorize your app, you can access his/her profile information or can tweet on behalf of him,follow/follow what ever access twitter give to your APP.

For more detail read there official documentation of [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)

Comment: I was already done the oAuth authentication. In my android application profile button is there when i was click that profile button it displays user profile info.

Comment: @user946456:Than better describe what exactly you want.Your question is not clear in that way

Comment: @user946456 - i think u want to show information of particular user without using id,password of that user,,right?