# How to Get twitter authentication name to android application?

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

I have created android application integrating with twitter and my application wants to authenticate the application by using a twitter user name and password for some operations. I want to display this authenticated user name in my application. Is there any way to get the authenticated user name to my application?

Comment: then you should probably look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use twitter REST api's "account/verify_credentials".
for more info https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials