# How to get user account information from Twitter using objective-c?

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, twitter-oauth

i have used oauth mechanism to let the user login via twitter in my app, on successful login it returns me the access taken, username and oauth_token_secret, i want to get the user account information from twitter like his location, date of birth, and other profile information. I have searched the Rest Api given on the twitter's official site but haven't found any such link.... so how to get the user 's account information? kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) call

```
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true
```

Comment: tell me how can i get the user's email address?

Comment: @JamalZafar You can't. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us

Answer (score 0):

Twitter-Kit Version 3.4.0 Here is function

```
-(void)userVerify:(NSString *)userID{
    NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"id": userID};
    NSError *clientError;
    // Objective-C
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:statusesShowEndpoint parameters:params error:&clientError];
    if (request) {
        [client
         sendTwitterRequest:request
         completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                      NSData *data,
                      NSError *connectionError) {
             if (data) {
                 // handle the response data e.g.
                 NSError *jsonError;
                 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:0
                                       error:&jsonError];
                 NSLog(@"%@",[json description]);
                 self.txtViewDetails.text = [json description];
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]);
                 self.txtViewDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]];
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
    }
}
```