# how can i get twitter email with dotnetopenauth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us)

I've pretty much got OpenID working using the DotNetOpenAuth library. Now I would like to get the email.

```
 public ActionResult OAuth()
    {
 var twitter = new WebConsumer(TwitterConsumer.ServiceDescription, TwitterTokenManager);
        AuthorizedTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = twitter.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        if (accessTokenResponse != null)
        {
            string accessToken = accessTokenResponse.AccessToken;
            string username = accessTokenResponse.ExtraData["screen_name"];
            // email goes here ??
            CreateAuthCookie(username, accessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it's not possible to get the users Email address from Twitter.

Take a look at the following

[Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us)