# Getting (omniauth-facebook) and (omniauth-twitter) work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I'm using:

- Ruby on Rails 4
- devise 3.0.3
- omniauth (1.1.4)
- omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
- omniauth-twitter (1.0.0)

I recently set up my `omniauth-facebook` and everything works fine. Now i want to add `omniauth-twitter` but somehow i mess things up, pretty bad.

**1.)** To set up my `Omniauth-Facebook` i did this (in a nutshell):

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**2.)** Added the columns "`provider`" and "`uid`" to my User model.

**3.)** Next, i declared the provider in my config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "App_ID", "App_Secret",
                                {:scope => 'email,offline_access',
                                 :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => 'lib/assets/cacert.pem'}},
                                 :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook}
```

**4.)** I edited my Model User.rb

```
# Facebook Settings
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
    user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
    if user.present?
        user
    else
        user = User.create(first_name:auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                                             last_name:auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                                             facebook_link:auth.extra.raw_info.link,
                                             user_name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                                             provider:auth.provider,
                                             uid:auth.uid,
                                             email:auth.info.email,
                                             password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    end
end
```

and added the attributes to devise:

```
:omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

**5.)** I edited the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**THE END**

Although this worked perfectly for Facebook, i tried for hours now to get this working for Twitter, and i just cant figure it out.

If someone, who has experience in this, or just knows the solution could help me set this up, i would be very thankful :)

Thank you guys, and sorry for the long Post.

**In Addition**

Twitter does not provide an :email Attribute so i have to Split up my User Registration Process i guess ?

My **Twitter** action in my **User Model**

```
# Twitter Settings
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth[:provider], :uid => auth[:uid]).first
    unless user
        user = User.create(:first_name => auth[:name],
                                             :user_name => auth[:screen_name],
                                             :provider => auth[:provider], :uid => auth[:uid],
                                             :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        )
    end
    user
end

# build auth cookie hash for twitter
def self.build_twitter_auth_cookie_hash data
    {
        :provider => data.provider, :uid => data.uid.to_i,
        :access_token => data.credentials.token, :access_secret => data.credentials.secret,
        :first_name => data.name, :user_name => data.screen_name,

    }
end
```

I had to migrate a confirmable for Users -> [How To: Add :confirmable to Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)

My Form's Problem, (At Least im getting to this poing now :) )

[image]

Comment: It always helps if you explain and/or display the actual errors that you are receiving.  And, a long post is not a problem.  The more information the merrier.  Yours is actually shorter than many.

Comment: can you put the `devise.rb` code for twitter

Comment: you don't need omniauth gem if you have the others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix your problem with the email you could just set a dummy mail, or add a second step where the user adds his/her email.

Dummy mail:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_dummy_mail, if self.provider == "twitter"

  private

  def set_dummy_mail
    self.email = "#{self.name}_email@example.com"
  end

end
```

**Or the second step option:**

Modify your controller to redirect to an add email step if the provider is twitter and the email is blank. Maybe you also have to modify your validations to allow email blank on create if the provider is twitter.

**UPDATE**: I did it like following:

Gemfile:

```
gem "devise"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "omniauth-twitter"
```

I used:

- devise version 2.2.3
- omniauth 1.1.4
- omniauth-facebook 1.3.0
- omniauth-twitter 0.0.17

If you are using different versions, you maybe must change a few things..

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
  post "account/create" => "users/accounts#create"
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # allow email blank for first create
  validates_format_of :email, :with => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?

  # facebook find method
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(:first_name => auth.extra.raw_info.first_name, 
                         :last_name => auth.extra.raw_info.last_name, 
                         :facebook_link => auth.extra.raw_info.link, 
                         :user_name => auth.extra.raw_info.name
                         :provider => auth.provider, 
                         :uid => auth.uid, :email => auth.info.email, 
                         :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                        )
      user.confirm!
    end
    user
  end

  # twitter find method
  def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth[:provider], :uid => auth[:uid]).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(:first_name => auth[:first_name], :user_name => auth[:user_name],
                         :provider => auth[:provider], :uid => auth[:uid], 
                         :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                        )
    end
    user
  end

  # build auth cookie hash for twitter
  def self.build_twitter_auth_cookie_hash data
    {
      :provider => data.provider, :uid => data.uid.to_i,
      :access_token => data.credentials.token, :access_secret => data.credentials.secret,
      :first_name => data.screen_name, :user_name => data.name,

    }
  end

end
```

app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  # callback action for facebook auth
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  # callback action for twitter auth
  def twitter
    data = session["devise.omniauth_data"] = User.build_twitter_auth_cookie_hash(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(data)
    if user.confirmed? # already registered, login automatically
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Twitter"
      sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication
    elsif !user.email?
      flash[:error] = "You must add an email to complete your registration."
      @user = user
      render :add_email
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Please confirm your email first to continue."
      redirect_to new_user_confirmation_path
    end
  end

end
```

app/views/users/omniauth_callbacks/add_email.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, :as => "user", :url => account_create_path, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => User.human_attribute_name(:email), :class => "input-medium" %>
  <%= f.submit "Finish registration", :class => "btn btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/users/accounts_controller.rb

```
class Users::AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    data = session["devise.omniauth_data"]
    data[:email] = params[:user][:email]
    user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(data)
    user.email = data[:email]

    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.registrations.signed_up_but_unconfirmed"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.failure", :kind => data[:provider].titleize, :reason => user.errors.full_messages.first
      render "users/omniauth_callbacks/add_email"
    end
  end

end
```

Maybe you have to modify the one or other part of my solution..you also could refactor the two methods in the user model (find_for_facebook_auth, find_for_twitter_auth) to work with one dynamic method. Try it out and let me know, if you still have problems. If you find any typo, please also let me know.. Also you should write tests to check everything within your system.

Comment: Hey Mattherick, i really like your method. I did it and changed a little bit the code for Rails 4 and my Devise. But im getting always a NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter | undefined method `provider'. Could you Check out my Github Repo ? -> https://github.com/Theminijohn/myapp

Comment: Ich bin hier ein bisschen überfordert :)

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? On which line? Can you post the stack trace pls.

Comment: I updated my answer.. check out find_for_facebook_oauth, find_for_twitter_oauth and build_twitter_auth_cookie_hash data.. the build_twitter_auth_cookie_hash generates a hash.

Comment: Im getting the Error: undefined method `confirmed?' for #<User:0x490a070>  ---> http://i.imgur.com/lJvkbTb.png

Comment: I searched and fixed the confirmable problem for Devise... but im getting a from error for my add email form. I update my Question and included the part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36656/discussion-between-mattherick-and-the-mini-john)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Could you please update the link to your app that you referenced as https://github.com/Theminijohn/myapp?

Comment: Hey @steady_daddy, I'm sorry I don't have this repo anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in gem file

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

do bundle and restart the server

after this add your app_id and secret key in config/initializer/devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-twitter"
config.omniauth :twitter, "app_id", "secret_key"
```

edit your user model

```
:omniauth_providers => [:facebook,:twitter]
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)

  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]                            
                         )

  end
  user
end
```

Add new controller file in

> app/controller/user/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
 def twitter
@user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

end

Add this link in your view file

```
<%= link_to 'sign in with twitter', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
```

Changes required in user model as twitter do not return user's email id:
Create a migration file to allow null values in user's email column:

```
class ChangeEmailToNullInUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
      change_column :users, :email, :string, :null=>true
   end

  def down
  end
end
```

after this you also need to override user model validations so add this in user.rb

```
def email_required?
   false
end
```

Note: Before performing this you should create your app on twitter and give proper callback path. Its is important as after authentication from twitter the controller would come back to the path which you specify in your app on twitter.

let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Hey Sagar, thanks for helping out! I set everything up, i get the connection trough twitter but i  get an error ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter

Comment: I updates my Question on how i get over that Cookie Overflow. I guess this is a viable Solution but please give it a look. Now i have those twitter Attributes Errors :(

Comment: Hey `The Mini John` I backtraced the issue. same issue i had faced it earlier main cause is that Twitter doesnt returns users email id (point to be noted) its twitter's policy the api is designed to do so, and in our devise  user model email is required field. I am updating my answer according to it so check it out

Comment: Hey Sagar, thanks for the digging, but i really need that email attribute in my App :( I'm Currently trying Mattherick's Answer above but running into problems...

Comment: ok if you want to set a dummy email id then you can set it through callbacks in user model

Comment: No No, im trying the Second Option. That when a user signs in via Twitter he is redirected to enter his email address.

Comment: ok but then to you either need to allow null values in email field or setup a default email in user model or as suggested by `Mattherick's` you can set dummy email. After doing this when the control returns to your site you can ask the user to input his/her email_id of twitter but you cannot verify if that same email_id is used for twitter login or not.

Comment: Hey Sagar could you give a look at my repo ? -> https://github.com/Theminijohn/myapp

Comment: undefined method `provider' for | NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Mattherick has a good solution for the email but I couldn't get the before_create to work.  A callback doesn't play nice with conditional if statements because anything after the comma is meant to be an options hash.  Therefore:

```
before_save :set_dummy_email, if self.provider == "twitter"
```

Popped me errors.

This how I fixed this:

```
before_save :set_dummy_email

def set_dummy_email
  self.email ||= "#{self.name}-CHANGEME@example.com"
end
```

This will only set an email if one is not given by the provider (ie: Twitter).

And then for a more 'universal' way of setting attributes (so you don't need a unique strategy:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.name = auth.info.name || auth.info.nickname
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email if auth.info.email
    user.save
  end
end
```