# Add Facebook authentication to my Ruby on Rails application with pre-existent email/password authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication, devise

I implemented email/password authentication in my application without using Devise (or similar). Now I want to add Facebook authentication maintaining also the email/password authentication method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `omniauth-facebook` gem and keep the email/password and the facebook login

http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

[Getting (omniauth-facebook) and (omniauth-twitter) work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504308/getting-omniauth-facebook-and-omniauth-twitter-work)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set up Devise to use your existing email/password authentication data, and then add Facebook support.

If your existing authentication is sane (you use standard hashing for the passwords, etc.) then this should be easy and straightforward. (If you have a weird setup, with stuff like plaintext passwords in the DB or stuff like that, it's probably better to start over anyway).

Going with a separate solution for Facebook, your using Devise just for the Facebook logins, will likely be more work in the end than migrating your existing solution.