# Getting email back from Twitter Oauth with Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth, devise

I've set up a basic rails application to use twitter oauth gem and devise and have been able to log in a user. However, my problem is I've now got my app white-listed and I would like to get a user's email back in the response. I've followed all necessary steps on the twitter side (setting necessary permissions, URLS, and reset keys) and have tried passing both

`include_email=true`

and

`include_email=email`

as a params when I initiate the oauth sequence. I feel like I've read and re-read the docs and tried few edge cases I thought might work based off of very little I've found on-line.

Any help with this? Something I'm missing if you've done this before?

Comment: Twitter does not give out emails of their users.

Comment: That is not correct. They do you must first white list your application and follow a number of steps including putting a terms of service on your site and also a privacy policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem. The omniauth gem was not the latest version which would include email. In my gem file I needed to declare '~> 1.2.1' where I had version 1.2.0 - - the new version includes the following changes you can read about here: https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/pull/96