# Get the email Id from the Twitter Friends in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, twitter

I am able to get the name & profile picture of the my followings & followers (i.e. commonly say friends) of twitter. It works fine.

**Question 1**
 Is there any way to get the email_id of the friends?

**Question 2**

Is there any way to know the friends `is_install` parameter the app which is use for sending the invitation?

Because in facebook response, we able to get the parameter `is_install` to know whether friend is already install the app or not.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The user's email address can not be retrieved via the API. Here is a similar thread:

[Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... and what about question 2?

Comment: Did you get any reference for the question 2??

Comment: I have no idea about that. You need to explore the SDK documentation

Comment: Thanks for reply..... So, conclusion is that there is no any api by twitter for retrieving the email_id and `is_install` parameter.

Comment: Bro if my answer has satisfied you, then accept the answer :)