# Fetch User's MailID while logging in by Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter

I need to fetch User's MailID in my app at the time of login by Twitter.Is it possible to take using twitter Rest API ? As far as i checked it is not possible.Other than that How can i able to fetch User's MailID ? Is there any solution for this ?

i hvae checked on this Rest API [Twitter Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) .But not possible to fetch User's mailID.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

u can get the user information  from Accounts frameworks for this user has to set the  twitter account in the device's settings see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504031/retrieving-twitter-user-data-with-ios-social-accounts-frameworks/18504115#18504115)

and also for your question see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-their-twitter-identity), it is not possible to get email id :(

Comment: Thanks Shan.But from this i dont get email address.i am getting id and username with account type details.

Comment: i added one more link check it

Comment: then fetching user's mailID in twitter login is not possible ? correct ?