# How to fetch email id from Twitter login using twitter4j library?

Tags: android

I see [Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-their-twitter-identity) link which said "we cant get email id from twitter" due to latest api authentication from API developer side. Is any solution to get email id after login from twitter? I am using twitter4j2.2.6 library.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution? please help me if there any.