# Spring Social Twitter Auth in one step

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am building a service that needs to manage the user authentication through Twitter API with Spring Social Twitter and return some basic user info such as the email.

The idea will be to make this process with no callbacks (avoiding `response.sendRedirect( authorizeUrl );`), providing the whole info from the client and letting the server to make the whole stuff.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get user email [using Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-their-twitter-identity). You need to ask user to give his email in your application directly.

You can try to simplify OAuth2 dance using implicit flow feature. See these links for more details:

- [OAuth2: the Implicit Flow, aka as the Client-Side Flow](http://techblog.hybris.com/2012/06/05/oauth2-the-implicit-flow-aka-as-the-client-side-flow/)
- [Google Accounts: Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)

But I am not sure that you can do it without any redirect at all. From Google link it looks like you have redirect in popup option.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have seen it. Finally I have found no option so I have used the regular 2-steps process.