# Can a Twitter app obtain user's email

Tags: twitter

I'm interested to know, is there a way I can obtain an email from a Twitter user, with legal means?

Create an app, that will pull a user's ID, email etc. Does Twitter API provide that information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying their Twitter identity using OAuth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-their-twitter-identity)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the user's email address through the API. This is a deliberate design decision by the Twitter API team.