# Creating a new user from Twitter using auth0 get nil email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, auth0

I am using auth0 for my rails application,I tried to sign in with social connection using auth0, this works fine with **google** and **facebook** but when I tried with **twitter** I am getting blank email for user and not able to sign in with the user having blank email.

Here is the response which I am getting

```
  {  
    "name": "XXXX",  
    "picture": "XXXX",   
    "lang": "en",  
    "screen_name": "XXXX",
    "clientID": "XXXXXX",  
    "user_id": "XXXXX",  
    "nickname": "XXXX",  
    "identities": [  
     {
        "access_token": "XXXX",
        "access_token_secret": "XXXX",
        "provider": "twitter",
        "user_id": XXXX,
        "connection": "twitter",
         "isSocial": true
     }   
   ], 
   "created_at": "2015-04-07T06:00:51.515Z" 
  }
```

How do I get user email for twitter using auth0

Comment: Twitter doesn't give email of the user

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Twitter API doesn't give email address of the user.

[Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-their-twitter-identity)