# Twitter Integration - How to get user Login Details?

Tags: android, twitter

Twitter Integration

I want to  get user email id,firstName,lastName after successful login.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
  AppConstants.auth_adapter_Twitter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
  AppConstants.auth_adapter_Twitter.authorize(getActivity(), SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.TWITTER);
} 

private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        AppConstants.auth_adapter_Twitter.getUserProfileAsync(new ProfileDataListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        System.out.println("ResponseListener " + error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        System.out.println("Dialog Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        System.out.println("Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");
    }



       private final class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener<Profile> {

        @Override
        public void onExecute(String provider, Profile t) {
            System.out.println("ProfileDataListener execute");

            System.out.println("social_id " + t.getValidatedId());
            System.out.println(t.getDisplayName() + "firstname " + t.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(" email " + t.getEmail());
            System.out.println("lastname " + t.getLastName());
            System.out.println("provider " + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
            System.out.println("SocialAuthError " + e);
        }
    }
```

I am using above code for login in twitter account to get login detail, but there is some problem please help me

Comment: "There is some problem". Maybe tell us about the problem then ?

Comment: above code work proper but m getting email ,lastname ,firstname  always null

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get Email from the twitter OAuth unless or untill your app is whitelisted. For more Info you can visit this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-his-her-twitter-identit)

If you have whitelisted your app than you can refer to this code to get user information-

Use the access token you get after

```
accessToken = twitterConnection.getOAuthAccessToken
(requestToken,editPinCode.getText().toString());

oHelper.storeAccessToken(accessToken);

Log.i("Access Token:", accessToken.getToken());

Log.i("Access Secret:", accessToken.getTokenSecret());

long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

User user = twitterConnection.showUser(userID);

user.getName();
```